# Defining 'resValue' using an existing string definition

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-resources

I'm interested in defining my many flavors of my apps more so in the strings.xml files rather than the build.gradle.  Given multiple flavors, I'd like a simplified release/debug variant:

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/prod_name"
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/beta_name"
    }
```

Then in each of my build flavors' custom res/values/strings.xml files, I would define each their own "prod_name" and "beta_name".  I also want to use this similar framework for defining providers' authorities etc...

This currently will build fine via gradle command-line, but fails to be recognized by Android Studio.

Android Studio Error:

I find this within 'generated.xml'

```
<!-- Values from build type: debug -->
<string name="app_name">@string/beta_name</string>
```

Which is typical of how one string references another.  But this time Android Studio gives me this error:

```
Error:(7, 29) No resource found that matches the given name 
(at 'app_name' with value '@string/beta_name').
```

I'm using Android Studio 2.1 Preview 5

Comment: Could you be more specific about what exactly "fails to be recognized by Android Studio" means?

Comment: ..w.hy don't you just put the right strings into the right resource directories? `src/release/res/values/strings.xml` for release specific strings, `src/debug/res/values/strings.xml` for debug builds?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my experience you can't resolve a `@string/my_string` in the `resValue` DSL. Gradle put the value as a simple string inside the resource file.

In this case you can use different folder to achieve it:

Just use:

```
src/release/res/values/strings.xml
src/debug/res/values/strings.xml
```

If you would like to use different resource for each build variant (build type+flavor) you can use:

```
src/flavor1Release/res/values/strings.xml
src/flavor1Debug/res/values/strings.xml
src/flavor2Release/res/values/strings.xml
src/flavor2Debug/res/values/strings.xml
```

Comment: What if I'm already dealing with multiple flavors?  I have my regular "res" directory, as well as my flavor res directories: "/one/res/", "/two/res" etc...  I was originally trying to just define "prod_name" and "beta_name" in each flavor's res subdirectory, thus minimizing a further factor of 2 multiplication of directories...

Comment: In this case just add only the strings (which have different values in the buildtype) in these files.

Comment: Can't find a great example in the documentation.  How do I go about defining the debug and release directories for each flavor.  I already have my main "res" as well as "one/res", "two/res", etc... for all of the flavors.

Comment: How is this different than using Gradle's `resValues`?

Answer (score 19):

This is actually possible. All you have to do is declare those strings as empty in your defaultConfig, like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    resValue "string", "prod_name", ""
    resValue "string", "beta_name", ""
}
```

Comment: And this won't conflict with the definitions in each flavor's strings.xml files?  The flavor's strings.xml file overrides gradle's 'defaultConfig'?

Comment: Note that this seems to be required since updating to Gradle plugin v3.5.0

Comment: This seems not to work anymore. I used it this way too in the past (when you wrote this answer)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible you can add res values inside the gradle for your build flavors

```
productFlavors {

   prod {
        dimension "default"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "your prod app name"    
    }


    staging {
       dimension "default"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "your staging app name"    

    }
}
```

Comment: The original aim was to keep all definitions in the various strings.xml files rather than having definitions being set in the gradle file directly.